# Django on VPS

Tags: django

Помогите решить такую проблему, поставил django на VPS, сделал проект и приложение, а как привязать его к домену, к папке /var/www не знаю. Как можно тестировать проект и приложение через веб интефейс,использую VPS(Ubuntu Server)?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/